# File.getCanonicalPath can't process NTFS streams?

Tags: java, io, ntfs

I'm using a simple Java program to get canonical path of a file,

```
import java.io.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        try {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to NTFS streams, it raises exception

```
C:\>java Foo c:\windows\system32\calc.exe::$DATA
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is inc
orrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
        at Foo.main(Foo.java:8)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use **::$DATA** instead use

java -jar Foo.jar "C:\Users\SamDev\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyThreads\dist\README.txt" $DATA

Answer (score 0):

if the File name contains
`* ?` you will get java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
`| :` you will get java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect